# Baby Rudin Ch. 8, question 6A, special functions

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Suppose $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$ for all real $x,y$.  Assuming that $f$ is differentiable and not zero, prove that

$f(x) = e^{cx}$,

where $c$ is a constant.

Solution: Since $f(x) \neq 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that $f(0) = 1$ (take $x=y=0$ in the definition of $f$).  This is where I am not following:  It then follows that $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$.  Then the proof goes on.  Can someone explain this intermediate step? (Ok I get this step now).

Next question: How does the fact that $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$ imply that the function $g(x) = e^{-xf'(0)}f(x)$ satisfy $g'(0)$ for all $x$?  Then that means that $g(x) = g(0) = f(0) = 1$ for all $x$?  This is what the solution I am reading says but I can't seem to understand the chain and why this makes sense.

Comment: Use the hypotheses on  $(f(x+h) - f(x))/h.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f(x) \dfrac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} $$
and take $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks Robert this helped.  I posted an edit to what happens next in the solution if you can help me with that too.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, you basically want to show $$f(x)=e^{cx}$$ i.e. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},$ $$\frac{f(x)}{e^{cx}} = 1 $$ So define the function $g$ as this quotient and prove it is constantly $1$. First differentiate and show $g'(x) = 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},$ then since $f(0) = 1 $ and $e^0=1$, $g(0)= 1$ as well.

That shows $g$ is constantly $1$ and thus $f(x)=e^{cx}$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$